# How to split a string based on given any condition in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am new to java. I need to split and group a string based on given condition in Java like the following example,

My sample input string is :

```
M102,M103,M104,M105,M102,M103,M104,M105
```

I need to split and group the string into an arrays based on the condition like if the string end with ","[eg. M102,] group into array1[] or begin and end with "," [eg. ,M102,M103,..,M104,] group into array2[] or begin with "," [eg. ,M105] group into arrray3[] like the following

```
    array1[]={M102}   
    array2[]={M103,M104..M104}  
    array3[]={M105}
```

For this,how to do string splitting with delimiter? can you help me to get this output?

Comment: Can you expain what actually need you

Comment: lokks like you are just looking for prefix and postfix and what's inbetween

Comment: can you give more suitable example input?

Comment: Use `yourString.split(String regex);`

Comment: actually i am having 1gb file which has customer id's like key and list of values pair.For my recommendation process, i need to split value part into group of id's like id's ends with comma [M102,], id's with comma on both sides[,M103,] and id's begin with comma [,M105].I need to get that id's with comma.if i use normal String.split() it deletes all commas.i dont know how to do.can you give me any idea to make simple way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(.+?),|,(?!.+?,)
```

You can split by this using regex.split.Just remove empty and `None` entries.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/1